# Cannot refresh listview with observablecollection

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to refresh my `listview` when an item is removed from it, but every time it gives me this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index.

Before updating the `ObservableCollection`, I do this:

```
    Groups = new ObservableCollection<RequestGroups>();
```

And then I fill it with this:

```
    var temp = (JArray)resultJson["data"];
            JArray jarr = temp;
            foreach (JObject contents in jarr.Children<JObject>())
            {
                Requests obj = new Requests();
                obj.Id = (int)contents["id"];
                Client c = new Client();
                c.address = contents["address"].ToString();
                c.phone = contents["phone"].ToString();
                c.name = contents["user"].ToString();
                obj.Client = c;
                obj.Date = contents["date"].ToString();
                obj.Duration = contents["duration"].ToString();
                obj.DurationText = "Duración: "+contents["duration"].ToString()+"h";
                obj.Price = "$" + contents["price"].ToString();
                String[] cDate = obj.Date.Split(' ');
                String cHour = cDate[1]+" "+cDate[2];
                obj.Hour = cHour;
                String[] date = cDate[0].Split('-');
                String title = months[date[1]] + " " + date[0];
                obj.Title = title;
                bool flag = false;
                foreach(RequestGroups rqG in Groups){
                    if(rqG.Title.Equals(title)){
                        rqG.Add(obj);
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag){
                    RequestGroups rq = new RequestGroups(title, date[1] + "-" + date[0]);
                    rq.Add(obj);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        Groups.Add(rq);
                    });
                }

            }
```

This is where I remove the items:

```
    private async Task UpdateRequest(int status,int idEvent)
    {
        HttpClient hTTPClient = new HttpClient();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Utils.baseUrl);

        Dictionary<string, string> dataToSend = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dataToSend.Add("session", Utils.loginKey);
        dataToSend.Add("eventId", idEvent+"");
        dataToSend.Add("status", status.ToString());
        string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSend, new KeyValuePairConverter());

        var contentVar = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/UpdateEvent", contentVar);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var resultJson = JObject.Parse(result);
                if ((int)resultJson["status"] == 0)
                {
                    await base.DisplayAlert((string)resultJson["msg"], "", "OK");
                    return;
                }
                else if ((int)resultJson["status"] == 1)
                {
                    //I'm currently trying to reload the whole view, before this was calling the method above.
                    await this.mainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MasterMenu.MainPage()));
                    await getRequests();
                }
                else
                {
                    await base.DisplayAlert("Error procesando la solicitud, intente más tarde", "", "Ok");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error update request: {0}", ex);
        }
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
```

If I leave it like that, UI will not update. Please help me, as I've been struggling with this issue for 2 days now. It happens exclusively on iOS.

Comment: Where is the code that shows when you delete the item from your `ObservableCollection` ?

Comment: I do it from backend, then I reload the item list.

Comment: I will edit post to add the whole thing.

Comment: @apineda I already added the whole thing

Comment: If you are removing items in your backend and then re-loading your entire list, there is really no point in using an ObservableCollection.

Comment: and which specific line is causing the exception?

Comment: Looks like you are always creating a new ObservableCollection instead of calling `Clear()` or even better removing the affected item like Jason said.

Comment: Already fixed the issue. The problem was generated because of an iOS version. Updated iOS and now it works just fine.

Comment: @Kay I tried both options, neither of them worked. I was truly desperate at that point, this is why the code I shared is a mess, I'm just trying stuff. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed after updating iOS. The problem was caused because of a buggy iOS version that had problems indexing objects. After updating, everything ran as smoothly as usual. If anyone runs into this issue (exclusively on iOS), try updating both iOS and Xamarin Forms.